# Computing a higher (2015) order partial derivative of $1/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}\text{.}$$

Find $$\frac{\partial^{2015} f}{\partial x^{2015}}\text{.}$$

Comment: Basically, i need to find the 2015th derivative of f with respect to x

Comment: Are you asking for the 2015'th *partial* derivative with respect to $x$, or is $y$ a function of $x$?

Comment: i am asking for the 2015'th partial derivative with respect to x

Comment: OK, I edited your question to show the partial derivative, as well as to make the expressions larger and more readable.

Comment: Yeah, it would have been much easier to evaluate it at $0$. @Kevin

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Hmm, the function is not even defined at $(0,0)$...

Comment: My guess is you were asked to compute this as some point of the $y$-axis (other than the origin, where the function has a singularity), and that the answer is supposed to be $0$ because this is an even function of$~x$. But in arbitrary points you certainly get a rather complicated expression.

Comment: It is defined at $(0,y)$ for $y\neq 0$, though. I meant only when $x=0$, not $(x,y)=(0,0)$. @HenningMakholm

Comment: Um... the appearance of the number 2015 sounds a lot like this might be from an ongoing contest. Please explain where this problem is from.

Answer (score 11):

I assume that you meant $\dfrac{\partial^{2015}f}{\partial x^{2015}}$.

**Hint:**
Split 
$$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{1}{2iy}\left[\frac{1}{x-iy}-\frac{1}{x+iy}\right]$$

Comment: This works since we know $n$-th derivative of $\frac 1 x$. But, what to do with $\frac{(x + iy)^{2016}-(x-iy)^{2016}}{2i}$?

Comment: I think that's $\sinh(2016\ln(x+iy))$. Not sure if it helps

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Use the geometric series:
$$\frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}.$$

Comment: What happens if $|x| \geq 1$?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the series will still give the form of any derivative.

Comment: While that might work treating everything formally and reconstructing a function from derivative of the series, it is problematic in a basic calculus course to take derivatives of a series that diverges.

Comment: @SimonS It is not problematic.  The corresponding series expansion about $x = \infty$ works just fine:  $$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{x^{-2}}{1-(-x^{-2})} = x^{-2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{-2n}, \quad |x| > 1.$$  Even for a basic calculus course, this should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Right and that's my point: one series alone doesn't work. Still have to figure what to do with the case $x = 1$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

We have tow series, one for $x<1$ and the second for $x\geq1 $ as follow

for $x<1$
$$\frac{1}{y+x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{y^n}
$$
$$z_x^{2015}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n-2015}}{y^n}\prod_{k=0}^{2014}(2n-k)$$
For $x\geq1 $

Firstly, we will take the first derivative of $\frac{1}{y+x^2}$ which equal $\frac{-2x}{(y+x^2)^2} $

The series of $\frac{-2x}{(y+x^2)^2} $

$$z_x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+2)y^n}{x^{2n+3}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+2)}y^nx^{-2n-3}$$
$$z_x^{2015}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{(-1)^{n+1}(2n+2)}y^nx^{-2n-3-2014}\prod_{k=0}^{2013}(-2n-3-k)$$